Cannot show snapshot While tests are running cause visual regression test fail in cypress
I am trying write  a visual regression test on a Iframe object, Some times the test failed because of the new screenshot have Cannot show snapshot While tests are running . This error message come from Cypress rather than the code itself. This message display occasionally.

  cy.get('iframe[title="test-title"]').compareSnapshot({
    name:'test-name'
  });

Besides, increasing test threshold, Is there any other way we can resolve this issue?

The <iframe> element is a static container on the web page that can display a whole new document. It is always present on the page, but it's contents may be dynamically loaded.
So, it's not a good candidate for snapshot comparison. You would be better off using the <body> element of the iframe's document. You probably also want to assertion some element inside the body is visible as well.
Use the cypress-iframe package which is pretty reliable in waiting for the content to load.
Then your test will be something like this -
// check the contents have loaded
cy.iframe('[title="test-title"]')
  .find('some-element-inside-iframe')
  .should('be.visible')

// take a snapshot of iframe body element
cy.iframe('[title="test-title"]')
  .find('body')
  .compareSnapshot({name:'snapshot-name'})

